# Show more significant figures of coefficients

Tags: python, pandas, stata, statsmodels

I'm running a number of regressions I want to superficially compare with Stata, to ensure my code works as I migrate from Stata to Python.

i.e `statsmodels.formula.api('x ~ y')` outputs

```
                coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      2.9420      0.287     10.265      0.000       2.380       3.504
```

Whereas Stata provides

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         med |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |    2.94203   .2866093    10.26   0.000     2.380268    3.503792
```

I'd essentially like the output to match exactly. I know this can probably done under the hood by saving the coefficients, but it's far easier at a glance.

Comment: Note also that Stata has options for controlling format of regression results, such as `cformat()` with `regress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (hacky) way I have achieved this is by editing the statsmodels library file `iolib\summary.py`, and including Stata-like rounding. It's not perfect, but it will do the job for the moment.

```
def forg(x, prec=3):
    if prec == 3:
    #for 3 decimals
        if (abs(x) >= 1e4) or (abs(x) < 1e-4):
            return '%9.3g' % x
        else:
            return '%9.3f' % x
    elif prec == 4:
        if (abs(x) >= 1e4) or (abs(x) < 1e-4):
            return '%10.4g' % x
        else:
            return '%10.4f' % x
    elif prec == 10: #stata like coefficient rounding
        return round(x,2)
    elif prec == 11: #stata like t-stat rounding
        return round(x,7)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to increase the number of decimal places so that you can visually compare the values, you can use

> pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)

replacing "2" with the number of decimal places you would like to display.

Note: this changes the number of decimal places for **all** floats in your dataframes.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't appear to do for the statsmodels output. I think it's going to be a matter of editing the codebase directly.

Comment: is the output text? I suppose there is a method to get the raw numbers (as DataFrame/Series?), and then use [String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

The following will print parameters with 6 decimal places

```
# Parameters with 6 significant digits
print(result.summary2().tables[1])
```

Here **result** is variable where you save your OLS model fitted to your data

Comment: At this time, this answer is the most useful with the updates since the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem where I would like to see more digits especially for the standard errors.

The workaround I found is simply dividing all the independent variables by a factor (for example, 100 if I want to see two more digits), and rescale the estimates with that factor. This approach does not involve modifying the library.